# How to add row value in fixed position into an array using PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I need to keep one row value from table in bottom position in an array using PHP and MySQL. Here is my table:

db_designation:

```
id      name

1       aaa

2       bbbb

3       Other

4       tttt
```

My query is below:

```
$sqldeg=mysqli_query($connect,"select * from db_designation order by id desc");
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sqldeg)) {
            $desdata[]=array("did"=>$row['id'],"dname"=>$row['name']);
}
```

Here I need this `id->3   name->Other` row from table value always come in last in the array `i.e-$desdata`.

Comment: I suggest you need another field on your table called Sequence or SortOrder or something, and ORDER BY that instead in your query.

Comment: I agree with ADyson that your data model does not adequately describe your data - however it should be named according the REASON you need this record to appear last or the fact it should appear last, not according to the method by which the outcome is achieved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do it at query, with ordering before getting to php with.

By id:

```
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN `id`=3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) ASC, `id` DESC
```

Or by name:

```
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN `name`='Other' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) ASC, `id` DESC
```

this will append 1 when `id` or `name` matches, otherwise zero (0), and will order in ASCENDING order.

So your query would be:

```
$sqldeg=mysqli_query($connect,"select * from db_designation ORDER BY (CASE WHEN `id`=3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) ASC, `id` DESC");
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sqldeg)) {
            $desdata[]=array("did"=>$row['id'],"dname"=>$row['name']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do like this

```
$others='';
$sqldeg=mysqli_query($connect,"select * from db_designation order by id desc");
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sqldeg)) {
    if(strpos($row['name'], 'Other')===false)
        $desdata[]=array("did"=>$row['id'],"dname"=>$row['name']);
    else
        $others=array("did"=>$row['id'],"dname"=>$row['name']);
}
$desdata[]=$others;
```